# Fixed (in world coordinates) lighting position in LWJGL?

Tags: java, lwjgl, lighting

I have some cube models and a lantern model in the "world" (with normals) and a light source which is placed in specific coordinates. The problem comes when I try move around the models, position of lightsource changes every frame to viewport position. Here is my initialization part of code, which contain lighting init:

```
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            GL11.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_SMOOTH);
            GL11.glClearDepth(1.0f);
            GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.75f, 1.0f, 1);
            GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_CULL_FACE);
            GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);  
            GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
            GL11.glDepthFunc(GL11.GL_LESS);
            GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
            GL11.glLoadIdentity();

            GL11.glHint(GL11.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL11.GL_NICEST);
            ByteBuffer temp = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(16);
            temp.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            byf = temp;
            GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT1, GL11.GL_AMBIENT, (FloatBuffer)temp.asFloatBuffer().put(lightAmbient).flip());              // Setup The Ambient Light
            GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT1, GL11.GL_DIFFUSE, (FloatBuffer)temp.asFloatBuffer().put(lightDiffuse).flip());              // Setup The Diffuse Light
            GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT1, GL11.GL_POSITION,(FloatBuffer)temp.asFloatBuffer().put(lightPosition).flip());         // Position The Light
            GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_LIGHT1);
            GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_LIGHTING);

            GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
            GL11.glLoadIdentity();


            GL11.glFogi(GL11.GL_FOG_MODE, fogMode[fogfilter]);                 
            temp.asFloatBuffer().put(fogColor).flip();
            GL11.glFog(GL11.GL_FOG_COLOR, temp.asFloatBuffer());             
            GL11.glFogf(GL11.GL_FOG_DENSITY, 0.35f);                           
            GL11.glHint(GL11.GL_FOG_HINT, GL11.GL_DONT_CARE);                  
            GL11.glFogf(GL11.GL_FOG_START, 1.0f);                               
            GL11.glFogf(GL11.GL_FOG_END, 5.0f);                                
            GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_FOG);
```

I have seen some similar problems but their solutions didn't help me at all. I know that the problem is with irregular order of setting Matrixes, but I have no idea which one (Matrix) and where I should change. 
I tried to place setting Modelview matrix before the init of lighting but it didn't work for me.

By the way, I don't want to set the correct light position every frame, it works for me but it can slow the render.

Answer (score 0):

Your'e probably using a code similar to this or glulookat().

```
GL11.glTranslatef(Camera.x, Camera.y, Camera.z);
GL11.glRotatef(Camera.roatationz, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
GL11.glRotatef(Camera.roatationx, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
GL11.glRotatef(Camera.roatationy, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

//Render stuff here
```

Your light has to move as well. :)

Comment: This answer is a little bit of a fragment, please consider adding a little more context.